# Presence of a <button> element prevents text being highlighted with React App in Web Component with Shadow DOM in Chrome

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, web-component, shadow-dom

A weird issue, but I have a minimum reproducable example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-architecture-hvrsd?file=/src/index.js

[image: screenshot from example showing non-working state]

[image: screenshot from example showing working state]

Using the divs at the top you can toggle between showing and hiding the button with the `WHY?` text, which will prevent and enable respectively, highlighting the text at the bottom `Try and Highlight This Text` and `You only can if the button isn't shown`.

I'm using a Web Component and Shadow DOM as this is for a chrome extension, and am looking to avoid conflicting styles.

You can comment out the web component stuff in `index.js` and just render the demo directly with `ReactDOM.render()` and this behavior will not be observed.

I am also not sure if it is limited to just `<button>` elements causing this.

EDIT: It works in Firefox, but not in Chrome or the newest Chromium Edge

```js
let shadow = document.getElementById("root").attachShadow({ mode: 'open', delegatesFocus: true });
const button = document.createElement('button');
button.innerText='Test';

const p = document.createElement('p');
p.innerText = 'Cannot highlight this in Chrome';
shadow.appendChild(button);
shadow.appendChild(p);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Your demo seems to work as-expected for me... what browser are you using?

Comment: @redouglas Chrome - you?

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned - Firefox latest

Comment: well, it looks like it has something to do with 
`const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({  ... delegatesFocus: true})`
if you set `delegatesFocus` to `false`, it will select just fine. MDN indicates this is experimental and chrome-only: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ShadowRoot/delegatesFocus

Comment: @redouglas yeah it is definitely the `delegatesFocus` property; it's apparently only supported in Chrome currently which is why the issue isn't present in Firefox

Comment: @redouglas feel free to post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I'm not sure of the inner-workings, it looks like it has something to do with `const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({  ... delegatesFocus: true})`. If you set `delegatesFocus` to `false`, selection will work just fine. MDN indicates this is experimental and chrome-only: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ShadowRoot/delegatesFocus

Comment: To add to this, what it does, is when a non-focusable area of the shadow DOM is clicked, the first focusable part is given focus and the shadow host is given any available `:focus` styling. An example can be seen here https://apearce.github.io/react-shadow-root/#delegates-focus